# Full Screen Intent Does Not Work

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, fullscreen

When use android full screen intent, the notification does not do anything and does not give any error messages. Why does this happen? This is the link of the give full screen intent tutorial https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Connection.html#onShowIncomingCallUi()

Comment: post what you have coded please.

Comment: gonna make an assumption since you didn't provide any code. fullscreen intents don't need to implement `intent service` or `Notification` use `AlarmManager` to start your `Activity`

Comment: AlarmManager won't show your activity if the app is killed. Am I right?

Comment: @WorieN As long as the Alarm has been set and the phone has not restarted (assuming you are not using `BOOT_COMPLETED`), the alarm will be triggered.